# How to provide Privatekey for Omnipay

Tags: php, laravel-5, omnipay

I am developing an wap app with laravel and  omnipay-alipay (https://github.com/lokielse/omnipay-alipay/wiki/Aop-WAP-Gateway) I followed the instructions:

```
$gateway = Omnipay::create('Alipay_AopWap');
$gateway->setAppId('201610100207.....');
$gateway->setPrivateKey('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');
//$gateway->setPrivateKey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----');
```

but I kept getting the error msg:

openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key.

I've tried different formats but in vain. How should I set the private key properly ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to my reading of the code, the private_key parameter is passed to PHP's openssl_pkey_get_private() function, i.e. this one:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php

By looking at your code above it seems that you need to use something like the line that you have commented out:

```
$gateway->setPrivateKey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIICXAI...
```

however each line of the private key file must be terminated with a new line (\n) character.

Use OpenSSL to create a PEM formatted private key file and then read that in using file_get_contents().

Comment: Don't forget to use double quotes when inserting newline characters: `"line1\nline2\nline3"`

Comment: It's important to note that PEM encoded files are fussy about formatting including line feeds.  They must use the Unix line feed character \n and not the Windows \r\n sequence.  This is why I said "Use OpenSSL to create a PEM formatted private key file" because that way you know that the private key will have the correct format and correct line ending characters.  Embedding a PEM file as a string in your code is not an ideal solution.